# Possible Controller or at least the functions executing twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

So I am getting this error: "GET http://localhost:8000/blogs/undefined net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE angular.js:12587".

It happens when I go to my main blog page and when I go to a blog category page. Looking at the network tab I get: 
 1. blog-home.html  200 xhr angular.js 12587 4.6kb 21ms
 2. all             200 xhr angular.js 12587 3.0kb 57ms
 3. undefined       pending xhr angular.js 12587 3.0kb 57ms 0kb

and the same when I go a blog category page. Ultimately they fail and kick the error above.

So before this gets voted down... I have read and tried here on stack: 
No luck. Maybe I missed something or typed something wrong. I'm totally dumbfounded and I feel this is clearly above my skill level. So here is a bunch of code... 
Server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');
var path = require('path');
require('colors');

var app = express();


app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'client/assets/images', '*****')))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended:true}))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
app.use(express.static("./bower_components"));

//app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {       
//    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: 'client'});
//});

require('./server/config/mongoose.js');

var routes = require('./server/config/routes.js');
routes(app);

var api_key = '*********';
var domain = '*********';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
 
var data = {
  from: '********',
  to: '********',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
};
 
mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log("I'm listening...".blue);
})
```

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Bridgeman">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="10 days">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noodp">
    <meta name="msnbot" content="noodp">
    <meta name="slurp" content="noodp, noydir">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; connect-src 'self'; img-src * data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data:; frame-src https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d44591.890384371676!2d-118.36723983279781!3d33.83006153459027!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1492366398808 ">
    
    
    <meta content="/assets/images/******_BigBearSnowTrail.jpg" itemprop="image">
    <link href="/assests/images/*******.ico" rel="shortcut icon">

    <base href="/" />

    <title></title>
  
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link href="assets/css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <script src="/factories/ContactFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="/factories/loginFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="/factories/blogFactory.js"></script>

    <script src="/controllers/contactController.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/servicesController.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/blogController.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/blogViewController.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/blogAWSController.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
  
    <base target="_blank">
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    <div ng-include='"templates/footer.html"'></div>

    
   
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>    
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

app.js  (As you see I tried to seperate the AWS category into its own controller and both get's fired when that page loaded)

```js
var Bridgeman = angular.module('Bridgeman', ['ngRoute']);

 Bridgeman.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$qProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, $qProvider){
   $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location){         
    return{
     'responseError': function(rejection){
      if(rejection.status == 401){
       $location.url('/');
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
     }
    });
   $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
     templateUrl:'partials/home.html',     
    }).when('/about', {
     templateUrl:'partials/about.html',     
    }).when('/services', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/services.html',
     controller: 'servicesController'
    }).when('/blog', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/blog-home.html',
     controller: 'blogViewController'
    }).when('/blogAWS', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/blog-aws.html',
     controller: 'blogAWSController'
    }).when('/blogSEO', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/blog-SEO.html',
     controller: 'blogViewController'
    }).when('/blogSecurity', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/blog-Security.html',
     controller: 'blogViewController'
    }).when('/blogBusiness', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/blog-Business.html',
     controller: 'blogViewController'
    }).when('/blogSportsTech', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/blog-SportsTech.html',
     controller: 'blogViewController'
    }).when('/blog-post/:id', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/blog-post.html',
     controller: 'blogViewController'     
    }).when('/contact', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
     controller: 'contactController'
    }).when('/login', {
     templateUrl:'partials/login.html',
     controller: 'loginController'
    }).when('/admin', {
     templateUrl:'partials/admin.html',
     controller: 'blogController'
    }).otherwise({
     redirectTo:'/'
    });
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }])

 Bridgeman.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
      $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
      $anchorScroll();  
  });
})
```

blog-home.html (This is the main blog page which fires off both functions in my blogViewController)

```html
<!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Blog Home 
                    <small>My insights just for you</small>
                </h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="/blog">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">Blog Home</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="blogs" ng-repeat="b in blogs | orderBy:'-createdAt' | filter:searchblogs">

                <!-- Blog Post -->
                <h2>
                    <p>{{b.title}}</p>
                </h2>
                <p class="lead">
                    by {{b._user.name}} in the {{b.category}} category
                </p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Posted on {{b.createdAt | date: "MMM. dd, yyyy"}}</p>
                <hr>
                <p>{{b.snippet}}</p>
                <hr>
                <p>{{b.content}}</p>                
                <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="/blog-post/{{b._id}}">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

                <hr>
              </div>
              <hr>
              </div>

            <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <!-- Blog Search Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Search my blogs</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchblogs">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.input-group -->
                </div>

                <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Blog Categories</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="/blogAWS">AWS</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/blogSEO">SEO</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/blogSecurity">Security</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/blogBusiness">Business Tips</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="/blogSportsTech">Tech in Sports</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div>

                <!-- Side Widget Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>My Blog</h4>
                    <p>Here is a collection of my genius (ha!) and tech insights. I'm sure sooner than later I will discuss Formula 1 tech but be assured there will be plenty of SEO and various web development tips/tools/tricks. And lets not forget some general business savviness I've learned over the years.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
```

blogViewController (where the functions are. Again, I commented out the getOneBlog and the error didn't happen. So what is triggering this fire and before the button is clicked?)

```js
Bridgeman.controller('blogViewController', function($scope, blogFactory, $location, $routeParams){
  console.log("in the blog VIEW controller");

  $scope.blogs = [];
  $scope.one = [];

  blogFactory.getAllBlogs(function(output){
    $scope.blogs = output;
    console.log(output);
  })

  blogFactory.getOneBlog($routeParams.id, function(output){
    $scope.one = output;
    console.log(output);
  })
});
```

blogFactory (no issues here that I am aware of)

```js
Bridgeman.factory('blogFactory', function($http){
  var factory = {};

  factory.submitNewBlog = function(input, callback){
    $http.post('/blogs/new', input).then(function(output){
      console.log("we just added a new blog");
      callback(output.data);
    });
  }
  //factory.submitNewComment = function(input, callback){
  //  $http.post('/comments/new', input).then(function(output){
  //    console.log("we just added a new comment");
  //    callback(output.data);
  //  });
  //}

  factory.getAllBlogs = function(callback){
    $http.get('/blogs/all').then(function(output){
      console.log("we just got all blogs");
      callback(output.data);
    });
  }

  factory.getOneBlog = function(blogID, callback){          //factory.getOneBlog = function(blogID, callback)
    $http.get('/blogs/' + blogID).then(function (output){          //$http.get('blogs/' + blogID).then(function (output){
      console.log(output.data);                             //callback(output.data);
      console.log("we just got one blog");
      callback(output.data);
    });
  }

  return factory;
});
```

routes (a couple of different styles here just tying different formats to solve this)

```js
var users = require('./../controllers/users.js');
var blogs = require('./../controllers/blogs.js');

module.exports = function(app){
 
 app.post('/reg', function(req, res){
 users.reg(req, res);
 });

 app.post('/login', function(req, res){
 users.login(req, res);
 });
 
 app.get('/blogs/all', function(req, res) {
        blogs.getAllBlogs(req, res);
    });

    app.get('/blogs/:id', blogs.getOneBlog);    //app.get('/blogs/:id', blogs.getOneBlog)       
    

    app.post('/blogs/new', function(req, res) {
        blogs.addBlog(req, res);
    });

 app.post('/contact', function(req,res){

  var api_key = 'key-2451a2b90a87be616ab68b8f7c8f97ea';
  var domain = 'sandbox7dedeb0d5d384b6a8ce4f49165204257.mailgun.org';
  var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
   
  var data = {
    from: 'Website inquiry <postmaster@sandbox7dedeb0d5d384b6a8ce4f49165204257.mailgun.org>',
    to: '*************com',
    subject: req.body.full_name+" has sent you a message",
    html:
     req.body.full_name+" ..."+     
     req.body.phone+" ..."+
     req.body.email+" ..."+         
       req.body.message
  };
   
  mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
    console.log("working...");
    if(!error)
      res.send("Your message has been sent");
    else
     res.send("Uh oh... something went wrong!");
  });
 });
}
```

blogs.js server side controller (no issue here... that I am aware of)

```js
var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog');

module.exports = (function() {
    return {
      getAllBlogs: function(req, res){
        Blog.find({}).populate([{path : '_user'}]).exec(function(err, b){
          if(err){
            console.log("there was an error when getting all blogs".red);
          } else {
            console.log(b);
            console.log("successfully got all blogs".green);
            res.json(b);
          }
        });
      },

      getOneBlog: function(req, res) {
        console.log('Rich band aid');
        if (req.params.id !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('there was an id', req.params.id); 
        Blog.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).exec(function(err, b) {        //({_id: req.params.id}, function(err,b){})
          if(err){
            console.log('error is', err);
            console.log("there was an error when getting the blog".red);
          } else {
            console.log(b);
            console.log("successfully got the blog".green);
            res.json(b);
          }
        });
       }else {
        console.log('no id');
       }
      },

      addBlog: function(req, res) {
        console.log("===========================".yellow);
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log("===========================".yellow);

        var b = new Blog({category: req.body.category, title: req.body.title, snippet: req.body.snippet, content: req.body.content, _user: req.body._user})
        b.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log("there was an error when saving a blog".red);
          } else {
            console.log(b);
            console.log("successfully saved the above blog".green);

            res.redirect('/blogs/all');
          }
        })
      }
    }
})();
```

and the mongoose db (no issue here... that I am aware of)

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create the message schema
var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 category: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 3, enum:['Security', 'Business', 'SEO', 'AWS', 'Tech in Sports']},
 title: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 3},
 snippet: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 3},
    content: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 3},
    _user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}    
}, {timestamps: true});

mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

PS... and yes I am aware of the CPS error for the frame-src and the font-src when you try to refresh the page. Super annoying.

Comment: Please check you angular path,

Comment: @RAj Thanks for the direction. I added the server.js as well as I hoping you give a more detail as to what you mean? Many thanks for taking the time and this noob out.

Comment: @RAj So I have been playing with the angular script tags and the only thing that made any sort of difference was when I moved my angular & angular-route script tags to the bottom of the index page. When I did this I could go to my blog homepage & just the page itself and the getAllBlogs fired. The getOneBlog did not fire off and did not get stuck pending. Unfortunately, though, none of the blogs rendered on the page.

Comment: please create jsfiddle, so I can debug the issue.

Comment: @RAj - thanks for the help but see the answer. Took some time but a friend and I figured a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out with a friend. Problem solved by wrapping the 2 functions into an 'if' statement. It may not be the proper solution but it works perfectly.

```js
Bridgeman.controller('blogViewController', function($scope, blogFactory, $location, $routeParams){
  console.log("in the blog VIEW controller");

  $scope.blogs = [];
  $scope.one = [];


  if ($routeParams.id) {
    blogFactory.getOneBlog($routeParams.id, function(output) {
    $scope.one = output;
    console.log(output);
    });
  } else {
    blogFactory.getAllBlogs(function(output) {
    $scope.blogs = output;
    console.log(output);
    });
  }  
});
```